# Dimensionar table layout de acordo com a orientação da tela

Tags: android-layout

Estou meio perdido na montagem das minhas telas no Android, não estou conseguindo fazer os elementos se adequarem às dimensões da tela. Coloquei `fill_parent` no `tablerows` e nos elementos dentro dele, mas os `editTexts` não se dimensionam e ficam como se estivessem em `wrap_content`, e quando eu giro a tela para horizontal o *layout* ocupa apenas uma parte da tela.

Na tela na vertical eu coloquei valores no `width` e ficou bacana mas não automático.

Como fazer para o meu layout ocupar toda a tela de forma automática?

A tela na vertical:

[image: a tela na vertical]

A tela na horizontal:

[image: a tela na horizontal]

O código do layout:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView 
        android:background="@drawable/borda"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Atendimento:"/>

    <EditText
        android:background="@drawable/borda"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/edtAtendimento"
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView 
        android:background="@drawable/borda"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Data/hora:"/>

    <EditText
        android:background="@drawable/borda"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/edtDataHora"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</TableRow>
```

Comment: Primeira sugestão: troque fill_parent por match_parent. fill_parent esta deprecated. Caso não funcione, tenho outra sugestão, mas ela envolve uma modificação drástica no layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que para fazer isto, vai precisar de uma configuração bem mais complexa, tenta colocando isto em seus EditText `android:layout_weight="1"`.

Comment: deu certo essa configuração no layout
com o android:layout_weight ele se dimensionou a largura da tela
obrigado